Looking for Android app to locate phone - no GPS, no intrusive "security" features
My wife and I often misplace our Samsung Android phones around the house. I'm looking for an Android (or Samsung?) app that, from my phone, can make her phone make a sound, and vice versa.

I could just call, but the phones are often left on silent
I currently use Google Family link, but it prevents us from using our Google accounts for other purposes (login on old streamer, Google wallet)
I do not want to track location via GPS, or even the option of it
Preferably no monthly payment...

All options I found were heavyweight security / parental control apps, which have too many intrusive and deep-permission-requiring features.

not exactly what you asked for, but last month I had to search for my smartband that went lost in the house and I ended up solving my problem in less than a minute with a free app that was a bluetooth compass -  reporting the proximity via the bluetooth device signal strenght.
The main cons are that  1) the phone has to be set to "discoverable"  2) it is not possible to force the phone to make a sound as you requested

@sigmud Thanks, that would help, except I can't guarantee that the phones would be discoverable...

If your phones are connected to Google and you have internet access, you can utilize the Find My Device feature to find your phone.
With it, you can play the sound of the phone's ringer regardless if it is on silent or vibrate. This would require you guys to login to each other account on browser in that moment to locate each other's phone

Tried it - for some reason it works only for my account+phone - for hers it says "no devices", although the device does have "find my device" enabled

@Jonathan Just to be clear, she does have a separate account?

Yes, she does has a separate account. If I log into her account on Find My Device (web, or app on my machine), it says "no devices". If I log on to my account, I see my phone, and can ring it.
